# using react router back and forth

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

i'm new to react(hooks typescript) world, here i have an icon when user clicks that it should go to '/menu' and when it is again clicked it should go to previous page, and if again clicked it should go to '/menu' so basically it should work like toggle.

am i doing this wrong :

```js
  import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);

  const history = useHistory();


    <Box  onClick={() => setMenu(!menu)}>
            {menu ? (
              <Link to={history.goBack}>
                <MenuIcon fontSize="large" />
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <Link to="/menu">
                <MenuIcon fontSize="large" />
              </Link>
            )}
          </Box>
```

Comment: You can see the options available to `Link` in the **react-router** docs. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link 

That's not how you would use `history.goBack`. The API for `Link` doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, `Link` can not be used this way. It expects the route not the function. How about using a div and placing onClick handler where you can navigate back through `history.goBack()`?

Comment: can you give an example code of that ? but with link i dont need to refresh

Answer (score 0):

The `to` property expect a string as value (path). if you don't know what the previous route is, I recommend you to create a context to store the previous route value:

```
const RouterContext = React.createContext();

const RouterProvider = ({children}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const [route, setRoute] = useState({
    to: location.pathname,
    from: location.pathname
  });

  useEffect(()=> {
    setRoute((prev)=> ({to: location.pathname, from: prev.to}) )
  }, [location]);
  
  return <RouterContext.Provider value={route}>
    {children}
  </RouterContext.Provider>
}
```

then:

```
const route = useContext(RouterContext);

<Box  onClick={() => setMenu(!menu)}>
 <Link to={menu ? route.from : "/menu" }>
     <MenuIcon fontSize="large" />
  </Link>
</Box>
```

Don't forget to add `RouterProvider` under Router component:

```
 <Router>
   <RouterProvider>
      ...
   </RouterProvider>
 </Router>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sxxqax) (About component has the go back option)

Comment: Warning: Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack

Comment: this will just hide it and not show the previous page

Comment: Do you know what the previous route is?

Comment: it can be what ever, i want to go to previous page

Comment: In that case you will need to store the previous location.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: The previous location is a route in the same app right?

Comment: yes ! it is i'm using react router dom { Link, Redirect, Route, Switch }

Comment: have any suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, let me know if this works

Comment: using your example code: these in my code are inside one component called Header :  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined

Comment: Is your Header component wrapped by RouterProvider? That error is because your component in outside the context

Comment: yes my header component is also inside RouterProvider

Comment: Try to console.log route property in RouterProvider, and do the same in your header component, the value should be the same